# Enabling net.ipv4.ip_forward for a container

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to enable `net.ipv4.ip_forward` on a container's network namespace?

---

**Manual**

From the host, I can enable it with manually with

```
sudo nsenter -t \
    $(docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' $CONTAINER_NAME) \
    -n sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and confirm that forwarding begins working within the container.

Is there a way to do this automatically whilst avoiding privileged containers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case of some sysctl parameters yes; `net.*` **is namespaced**, so `net.ipv4.ip_forward` can be enabled per Pod (per container).

Follow the [Using Sysctls in a Kubernetes Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/) guide for details and gotchas.

### Longer answer

While `net` **is namespaced**, not all sysctl variables can be set in namespace. Some simply await for a ["namespacify"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/13b287e8d1cad951634389f85b8c9b816bd3bb1e) patch, but others will possibly never get implemented. In the specific example of `net.ipv4` one could browse [`include/net/netns/ipv4.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/net/netns/ipv4.h#L44) to see what is supported at the moment. Such support of course depends on the actual kernel version.

In case you wanted to "empirically" verify whether *sysctl* (the actual kernel facility, not the tool) supports a particular variable, you could do something like this (as root):

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
# unshare --net sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

As you can see *sysctl* (the tool) running in a new namespace could set `net.ipv4.ip_forward=0`; also that it did not affect the parent namespace.

An example of a variable that *can't be set* in a namespace (no support for it at the moment):

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_msgs_burst
50
# unshare --net sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_msgs_burst=42
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_msgs_burst: No such file or directory
```

An example of a variable that is *not namespaced* would be `vm.nr_hugepages`. This variable exists in namespaces, but the `vm` subsystem itself is [**not namespaced**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) (setting this variable will affect all processes):

```
# sysctl vm.nr_hugepages
vm.nr_hugepages = 0
# unshare sysctl vm.nr_hugepages=1
vm.nr_hugepages = 1
# sysctl vm.nr_hugepages
vm.nr_hugepages = 1
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a reference to some code or kernel docs that indicate that `net.*` is namespaced? I can see the kubernetes docs indirectly talk about it, but I'd love to see linux docs for it.

Comment: You are quite right, the answer was really not very well detailed; I've edited it.