# how to change kernel parameters of a pod in Openshift?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kernel, openshift

Trying to run Elastic Search 6.2.4 on Openshift but it is not running and the container exits with the code 137.

```
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,148][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] 

loaded module [ingest-common]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [parent-join]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [percolator]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [reindex]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [repository-url]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,149][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded module [tribe]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,150][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [ingest-geoip]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,150][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [ingest-user-agent]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,150][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [x-pack-core]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,150][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [x-pack-deprecation]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,151][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [x-pack-graph]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,151][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [x-pack-logstash]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,151][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [x-pack-ml]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,151][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [x-pack-monitoring]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,151][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [x-pack-security]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,151][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [x-pack-upgrade]
[2018-06-01T14:24:58,151][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [jge060C] loaded plugin [x-pack-watcher]
[2018-06-01T14:25:01,592][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [controller/131] [Main.cc@128] controller (64 bit): Version 6.2.4 (Build 524e7fe231abc1) Copyright (c) 2018 Elasticsearch BV
[2018-06-01T14:25:03,271][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [jge060C] using discovery type [zen]
[2018-06-01T14:25:04,305][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2018-06-01T14:25:04,305][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [jge060C] starting ...
[2018-06-01T14:25:04,497][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [jge060C] publish_address {10.131.3.134:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2018-06-01T14:25:04,520][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [jge060C] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2018-06-01T14:25:04,531][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [jge060C] stopping ...
[2018-06-01T14:25:04,623][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [jge060C] stopped
[2018-06-01T14:25:04,624][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [jge060C] closing ...
[2018-06-01T14:25:04,634][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [jge060C] closed
```

As you can see from the logs, the vm max heap size has to be increased. As it turns out to be a kernel parameter, how to change that for the pod that is running ES?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel *command line* parameters can't be changed per pod, but `vm.max_map_count` is parameter you can change via sysctl.

See these two similar SO question for a solution:

- [How to pass `sysctl` flags to docker from k8s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439372/how-to-pass-sysctl-flags-to-docker-from-k8s)
- [Enabling net.ipv4.ip_forward for a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961956/enabling-net-ipv4-ip-forward-for-a-container)

There is also a more general explanation in the official [Kubernetes documentation on sysctl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/sysctl-cluster/)

Comment: I am manually adding it to the sysctl.conf of all the worker nodes via ansible script. Let's see if it fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change kernel parameters for individual pods; they have to be fixed in the underlying operating system.